How to raise a ValidationError in the ModelForm's save method in Django?
I want my ModelForm error handler to show validation errors from the save() method just like they do in the clean() method - i.e. as a warning on the admin form, instead of generating a 500 page.
The code flow is as follows, in admin.py:
class XForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super().save(**kwargs)
        try:
            self.instance.update_more_stuff_based_on_extra_fields_in_the_form()
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValidationError(_("Earth to Monty Python."))
        return self.instance


class XAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = XForm

admin.site.register(X, XAdmin)

This results in a debugger's 500 page when the validation error is triggered, not the preferred admin warning.
Note: The following question addresses the similar problem of raising a validation error within the model's save method. Here we want to raise the error in the model form's save method.

Why do you not move that validation to the clean method instead?

@AbdulAzizBarkat Validating in the clean method would result in duplication of the validation process, resulting in performance downgrades. That can be done as a last resort though

The problem with your process though is that unless you're using transactions your solution causes only a partial update of the database. Also it doesn't really look like you're doing much validation but rather depending on the database throwing an error.

You can create a custom ModelAdmin for this model and override the 'save_model()' method.
class XAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
form = XForm

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    try:
        obj.save()
    except ValidationError as e:
        for field, errors in e.message_dict.items():
            form.add_error(field, errors)
        return super().form_invalid(form)


The add_error method didn't work for me, somehow resulting in a TransactionManagementError
